# How to upload web service like dotnenuke module?

Tags: .net, web-services, asmx, dotnetnuke

I have web service project in my dotnetnuke/desktopmodules folder. I setup to dll goes directly to the dotnetnuke/bin folder. This web service searve to embeded devices can access the rest of the application logic. My dotnetnuke modules use the same data access project as this webs ervice. My question is how to put this web service project on server (localhost/relhost). I can add modules but service can't?

Web service is 'asmx'

Ok I added one empty ascx dnn file and upload module with asmx on my dnn site. But how to access this asmx now?

Comment: Can you access `http://localhost/relhost/DesktopModules/ServiceProject/Service.asmx`?

Comment: I can't :( I have no idea how to access it :(

Comment: Try upgrading to DNN 5.6.2 and see if that helps (there was a bug in DNN 5.5-5.6.1 with accessing resources like that)

Comment: It works ;) I am not sure what was the problem but it works ;)
http://localhost/dnn/DesktopModules/Test.WebService/Service1.asmx

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From DNN 5.5.0 to DNN 5.6.1, there was a bug in the processing of certain files.  See Scott Schlesier's blog [Just Let ASP.Net handle it](http://www.dotnetnuke.com/Resources/Blogs/tabid/825/EntryId/3015/Just-let-ASP-Net-handle-it.aspx) for some more details.